# Methanol vs water. Acidic strength

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Why $CH_3OH$ is more acidic than $H_2O$ while the same is opposite for other alcohols?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/is-methanol-really-more-acidic-than-water

Answer (score 2):

The question is based on the assumption, that water has a pKa of 15.7 which is usally not correct.

As a paper mentioned in this thread [What is the Real Pka of WATER](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108533/what-is-the-real-pka-of-water) the pKa of water in water should be 14.It might be different when water is a reactend in organic solvents, for that the paper mentioned by the thread author is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Like other alcohols Methanol is also a weaker acid than water; sodium methoxide undergo easy hydrolysis with water forming methanol and sodium hydroxide, the equilibrium being more in favour of the products. Since methoxide ion is a stronger base than hydroxide the parent acid methanol must be weaker acid than water 
$\ce{CH3O^-Na^+ + HOH<=>CH3OH + Na^+OH^-}$